# Go CD Trigger User always gets value of 'changes' in multi-staged pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, go-cd

We are using Go CD for our CI pipelines. We have created multiple Go CD users and all of them have access to trigger any pipeline in Go CD.

We use multiple pipelines for completing the dev-to-prod cycle, however, we noticed that we can achieve the same by using a single pipeline with multiple stages (Saving disk space caused by multiple pipelines), each representing deployment to an environment (i.e. stag, prod).

Our requirement is to get the GO_TRIGGER_USER, set up by Go CD system, and based on this information do some decision making in a custom script. It works perfectly fine for single stage builds i.e. if changes are pushed to repository triggering the pipelines, GO_TRIGGER_USER environment variable gets the value of 'changes' otherwise its set to the user name of the Go CD user who manually triggered the pipeline.

Problem occurs on multi-staged builds; starting from 2nd stage in the pipeline, which always gets GO_TRIGGER_USER set to 'changes' even if the pipeline is triggered manually by a Go CD user.

Any idea or workaround to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Use the API to fetch the data about the first stage in the pipeline [Stages API](https://api.gocd.io/current/#stages). I use this from Python and it's not too onerous.
2. Write the meta-data you want to a flat file and export as an artefact between the stages.